# Modify the example named UART_HyperTerminal_IT to enable UART reception interrupts on STM32F4?

Tags: stm32, interrupt, uart

I'm developing a project with STM32F4 and I need to enable the UART6 receive interrupt. I have used STM32CubeMX to enable the UART6 and in the STM32CubeMX I have enabled the NVIC USART6 global interrupt.

### The example `UART_HyperTerminal_IT`

I have followed the example `UART_HyperTerminal_IT` which is installed by the package `STM32Cube_FW_F4_V1.27.0`.
The code is more recent but not so different from [this example code](https://github.com/JoeMerten/Stm32-Tools-Evaluation/tree/master/STM32Cube_FW_F4_V1.9.0/Projects/STM32469I_EVAL/Examples/UART/UART_HyperTerminal_IT).

I would like to modify the example to send back every character received from UART6 on the same UART6 (echo). So I have removed all the code of the example that sends data by the UART and wait data from the UART.

I have initialized the UART6 by the following code:

```
UartHandle.Instance        = USART6;

UartHandle.Init.BaudRate   = 115200;
UartHandle.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
UartHandle.Init.StopBits   = UART_STOPBITS_1;
UartHandle.Init.Parity     = UART_PARITY_NONE;
UartHandle.Init.HwFlowCtl  = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
UartHandle.Init.Mode       = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
UartHandle.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;

if(HAL_UART_Init(&UartHandle) != HAL_OK) {
    /* Initialization Error */
    Error_Handler();
}
```

The previous code is very similar to the example code (I have changed only *baud rate* and the *parity*).

### My interrupt routine

I have defined the function `USART6_IRQHandler` in the file `stm32f4xx_it.c` as in the code below:

```
void USART6_IRQHandler(void) {
    unsigned char ch;
    
    uint32_t isrflags   = READ_REG(huart6.Instance->SR);
    uint32_t cr1its     = READ_REG(huart6.Instance->CR1);   
    
    if (((isrflags & USART_CR1_RXNEIE) != RESET) && ((cr1its & USART_CR1_RXNEIE) != RESET)){
        huart6.Instance->SR;
        ch = huart6.Instance->DR;
        HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart6, &ch, 1, 1000);
    }

    HAL_UART_IRQHandler(&huart6);
}
```

In the [readme file](https://github.com/JoeMerten/Stm32-Tools-Evaluation/blob/master/STM32Cube_FW_F4_V1.9.0/Projects/STM32469I_EVAL/Examples/UART/UART_HyperTerminal_IT/readme.txt) of the example I have found this sentence:

> This example shows how to ensure UART Data buffer transmission and reception with
> Interrupt.

The sentence says that in the example the Interrupt is enabled, but if I try to send data to the UART6 the interrupt routine `USART6_IRQHandler()` is not called.

I think that the UART6 Receive Interrupt is not enabled, but how can I enable it? Is there a specific bit in some register that must be set?

Thanks

---

[This post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12543076/usart-receive-interrupt-stm32) speak about this topic but I think is too old for my STM32F4.

[This other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27468358/uart-receive-interrupt-enabled-but-with-no-isr) is old too.

Comment: Do you ever set `USART_CR1_RXNEIE` in `CR1`?

Comment: No I don't.. How can I set it? Can you write the code necessary?

Comment: `huart6.Instance->CR1 |= USART_CR1_RXNEIE;` You possibly have other problems, but maybe this will at least get the interrupt to fire.

Comment: Ok Thank you very much. I have added `huart6.Instance->CR1 |= USART_CR1_RXNEIE;` to my code and now the echo on UART6 works!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **@pmacfarlane**'s comment I solved the problem of the lack of reception interrupts in the example `UART_HyperTerminal_IT`.

So I confirm that the only modification needed to obtain the echo of the characters receives from UART6 is the addition of the instruction `huart6.Instance->CR1 |= USART_CR1_RXNEIE;`.

### Initialization of UART6 with reception interrupts enabled

So the initialization code for the UART6 becomes:

```
huart6.Instance        = USART6;

huart6.Init.BaudRate   = 115200;
huart6.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
huart6.Init.StopBits   = UART_STOPBITS_1;
huart6.Init.Parity     = UART_PARITY_NONE;
huart6.Init.HwFlowCtl  = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
huart6.Init.Mode       = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
huart6.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;

if(HAL_UART_Init(&huart6) != HAL_OK) {
    /* Initialization Error */
    Error_Handler();
}

// ---> enable reception interruptions
huart6.Instance->CR1 |= USART_CR1_RXNEIE;
```

**Note.** In the previous code I have substituted the variable `UART_HandleTypeDef UartHandle` used in the **UART_HyperTerminal_IT** example with the variable:

```
UART_HandleTypeDef huart6;
```

### Interrupt routine implements echo

The code of the interrupt routine presented in the question remains exactly the same:

```
void USART6_IRQHandler(void) {
    unsigned char ch;
    
    uint32_t isrflags   = READ_REG(huart6.Instance->SR);
    uint32_t cr1its     = READ_REG(huart6.Instance->CR1);   
    
    if (((isrflags & USART_CR1_RXNEIE) != RESET) && ((cr1its & USART_CR1_RXNEIE) != RESET)){
        huart6.Instance->SR;
        ch = huart6.Instance->DR;
        HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart6, &ch, 1, 1000);
    }

    HAL_UART_IRQHandler(&huart6);
}
```

The `USART6_IRQHandler()` function retrieves the received char and sends it immediately back implementing the echo of every char received.

### While loop empty

That's all, the while(1) loop is completly empty:

```
while(1) {
   // empty loop
}
```